# Elegant way to pass empty closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In Swift, I often have to pass a noop closure to a method just to comply with the method's expected parameters (arity). In the good old days of Obj C, one could pass `nil` for a noop callback and be done with it. Is there a quicker more elegant way to do that in Swift without passing an empty block like below?

`UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in }) // do nothing in callback`

Complete example:

```
import UIKit

class UIAlertControllerFactory {
    class func ok(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
        var alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        })
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        return alertController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**In this case**, you can pass `nil`, because the handler is an `Optional`:

```
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
```

The general way, if you can't pass `nil`:

```
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in })
```

Comment: I swore nil didn't work in one of the betas. Thanks, I also like the _ approach.

Comment: `handler` is of type `((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!`, what means that it is an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional. That why you can pass `nil` for this parameter. It is documented (see my answer for more details).

Comment: A `!` suffix means an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`, which Apple mostly uses (in APIs) to mean that they haven't checked whether `nil` is legal or not. In iOS 9.0, they changed the type to `((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?`, which means they verified that `nil` is allowed.

Answer (score 10):

You could define a **noop** to be used as a default closure that does nothing: (Reference: https://realm.io/news/closures-api-design)

```
func noop() {}

func noop<T>(value: T) {}

func noop<T>() -> T? { return nil }

func noop<T, S>(value: T) -> S? { return nil }
```

To use:

```
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", 
                             style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
                           handler: noop)
```

Comment: Handy for cases where a parameter that takes a closure isn't nullable. (The `UIAlertAction` case in the question is nullable, though.) You might also need a few other variants for the APIs that don't take `@convention(block)` closures.

Answer (score 5):

According to Xcode documentation, `UIAlertAction` has a `convenience init` method with the following declaration:

```
convenience init(title: String, style: UIAlertActionStyle, handler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!)
```

As you can see, the `handler` parameter is an **Implicitly Unwrapped Optional** of type `((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)!`. So you may pass `nil` for it. For example, you can create an `UIAlertController` instance that contains one `UIAlertAction` with `handler: nil`:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Therefore, you don't need to create an empty block for `handler`.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIAlertAction {
    convenience init(title: String, style: UIAlertActionStyle) {
        return self.init(title: title, style: style, handler:  { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in })
    }
}
```

and just leave out the last argument. You can put this into your "factory".